# Relating Two Tables Based on Nearby Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

In my application a user can login and then share something. I'd like to get their latest login information relative to the date that they shared something (e.g., the `MAX` login date that was before than the share date)

I have two tables (they are related by `csh.actor = ul.user_id`):

**CollectionShares (csh)**

```
| id | actor | shareDate
```

**UsersLogins (ul)**

```
| id | user_id | httpReferer | browser | ipAddress | loginDate
```

One of my attempts:

```sql
SELECT
    csh.shareDate AS shareDate,
    ul.httpReferer AS httpReferer,
    ul.browser AS browser,
    ul.ipAddress AS ipAddress,
    max(ul.loginDate) AS nearestLastLoginDate
FROM collectionsharehistory csh
JOIN userslogins ul ON 
    csh.actor = ul.user_id 
    AND 
    ul.loginDate <= csh.shareDate
GROUP BY csh.id;
```

This actually seems to be getting the right `ul.loginDate`, but the other `ul` columns are incorrect and do not seem to actually match up with the returned `loginDate`.

Comment: What happens if the user has no share after the last login date? Do you want to go back and look for previous logins as well?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos if the user has NOT shared, then I do NOT want to look up login information. If the user has shared, then I DO want the latest login information (relative to that share date).

Comment: Perhaps the user has shared something, but NOT after the *last* login. What do you want to get in this case?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I'd want to get the most recent login that was before they shared. Not necessarily the _last_ login.

Comment: IMHO this is not an exact duplicate of the referred post as it is a bit more complicated. @MarkFeltner have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/819a5/2) for a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for putting together the fiddle @GiorgosBetsos. At first glance, it appears to work. It has some syntax and keywords I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Although this question may have duplicates, the stated question was for an overall maximum rather than a relative maximum.  That makes the questions quite different.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos this is working! If you post an answer I'll accept! Would love if you wouldn't mind explaining your logic and the use of variables (e.g., `@rn`) in your code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ul.id, ul.user_id, ul.ipAddress, ul.loginDate, csh.shareDate                  
FROM UsersLogins AS ul
INNER JOIN CollectionSharesHistory AS csh 
  ON ul.user_id = csh.actor AND ul.loginDate <= shareDate
```

in order to get all user logins having a related post-dated `CollectionSharesHistory` record.

Using variables you can select the required records out of the derived table produced by the above query:

```
SELECT id, user_id, ipAddress, loginDate, shareDate
FROM (
  SELECT id, user_id, ipAddress, loginDate, shareDate,
         @rn := IF (@user <> user_id,
                   IF (@user := user_id, 1, 1),
                   IF (@user := user_id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)) AS rn
  FROM ( ... above query here ... ) AS t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @user := -1, @rn := -1) AS vars
  ORDER BY user_id, loginDate DESC, shareDate ASC ) AS s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

`@rn` variable is used to enumerate records within each `user_id` partition. Once `user_id` changes `@rn` is reset and enumeration starts again at 1.

The `ORDER BY` clause places the required record at the top of each `user_id` slice. Hence, we can easily select the required row using an outer query with a `WHERE s.rn = 1` clause.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/819a5/2)